# Blazor Server NavLink Formatting?

Tags: user-interface, blazor-server-side

I'm terrible at front-end/UI work, but I'm stumbling through a Blazor server app.  I've run into a weird (but minor) problem.  In my NavMenu I have some NavLinks that use the "href" and some that use the "onclick".  The "onclick" ones don't look quite right: when I hover over them they appear like text, not something clickable.  I can click on them and the functionality is correct, but the mouse cursor is incorrect.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [NavLink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.routing.navlink?view=aspnetcore-5.0) in Blazor looks at the URI and the href property of the tag to decide when to set its "active" css class or not. So those onclick will likely have the "active" class on it.